# What statistical analysis test can be used to find the direction of effect?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, continuous-data, interval-censoring

I'm doing research on the effect of strategic video game play on students' mathematical ability. My independent variable is the number of hours spent playing strategic games daily, but my data is not continuous; rather it goes by interval range (e.g., <1 hours, 1+ hours, 2+ hours, 3+ hours). Meanwhile, my dependent variable is the students' first-semester grade on the Math subject, which is continuous in nature (e.g., 95.43, 97.77, 86.83).

I tried searching for ways to do this online, but the only solution I found was to visualize the data and see the direction from there, but I was wondering whether there was a more statistical and mathematical approach to this. I'm also thinking about using ANOVA, but I'm not sure whether that would be possible.

Answer (score 7):

You could try linear regression, but if by "direction of effect" you mean "causal direction," then you cannot prove that with regression (or any statistical approach alone for that matter). All you can find out is whether there is a relationship and how strong it is. In order to show the direction of causation, you'd need an experimental (or similarly strong) design in which you ideally randomly assign individuals to groups (computer games vs. control)/manipulate the independent variable and then measure the dependent variable later on.

Assuming your design is non-experimental, you could try statistically controlling for potential confounding variables (if you have measured them) by adding them as "covariates" (additional predictors) to the regression model.

Answer (score 5):

As Christian [noted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/642553/362671), this is a problem that can be easily tackled by linear regression given the simplicity of the design. The one caveat I would add is that because your dependent variable is an interval scale item, you may need to consider what the residual term for your regression should be.

Two possible options here are [interval regression](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/interval-regression/#:%7E:text=Interval%20regression%20is%20used%20to,a%20generalization%20of%20censored%20regression.) and [ordinal logistic regression](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/), each with their own strengths. The former can be interpreted the same as any normal OLS regression, while the latter is more for understanding the probability of being assigned to one of the responses.